# Load localized resources

Tags: java, localization

In a project I'm working on, I'd like to load different resources depending on the current locale. With strings, this is pretty easy: just create a resource bundle by adding some files, for example `Localization.properties` and `Localization_de.properties` and then load it via `ResourceBundle.getBundle("domain.project.Localization")`.

But how do I load localized resources that are not simple strings?

Specifically, I'd like to load images and HTML files based on locale. It would suffice to get the correct URL to that resource. For example, I'd like to have a `Welcome.html` and `Welcome_de.html` file and load the later when the current locale is German.

Simply using `getClass().getResource("Welcome.html")` doesn't work, it's always returning exactly that file and doesn't do locale handling. I haven't found a convenient way to solve this yet, apart from manually messing with the filename based on the current locale.

One solution I came up with is to add a key to my `Localization.properties` file that contains the name of the correct localized HTML file. But this feels hacky and wrong.

Note that this is not an Android application, just a standard Java 8 desktop app.

Comment: Why not just putting the files + localization maps in different folders? Like "/LANGUAGE/img/image1.jpg" where language could be "DE" or "EN" or whatever? So you'd just need to hava the language stored somewhere [and maybe need to handle missing files (fallback on a ressource that is definitely complete?)]

Comment: @Cyphrags: That's actually a good idea. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually turned out to pretty easy to get the same behaviour as `ResourceBundle.getBundle`. I've [looked at the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ResourceBundle.java#ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Locale%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%2Cjava.util.ResourceBundle.Control%29) and found that the most important part for handling of the locales and filenames is [ResourceBundle.Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html).

So here's a simple method that returns the URL to localized resource (following the same filename scheme as resource bundles) without caching and support for just the current locale:

```
/** Load localized resource for current locale.
 * 
 * @param baseName Basename of the resource. May include a path.
 * @param suffix File extension of the resource.
 * @return URL for the localized resource or null if none was found.
 */
public static URL getLocalizedResource(String baseName, String suffix) {
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    ResourceBundle.Control control = ResourceBundle.Control.getControl(ResourceBundle.Control.FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    List<Locale> candidateLocales = control.getCandidateLocales(baseName, locale);

    for (Locale specificLocale : candidateLocales) {
        String bundleName = control.toBundleName(baseName, specificLocale);
        String resourceName = control.toResourceName(bundleName, suffix);

        // Replace "Utils" with the name of your class!
        URL url = Utils.class.getResource(resourceName);
        if (url != null) {
            return url;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If someone wants to extend it to support generic locales as an argument: the important part in the `ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl` implementation is:

```
for (Locale targetLocale = locale;
     targetLocale != null;
     targetLocale = control.getFallbackLocale(baseName, targetLocale)) {
         List<Locale> candidateLocales = control.getCandidateLocales(baseName, targetLocale);
         ...
}
```

The last entry of `getCandidateLocales` is the empty locale (`Locale.ROOT`). It should be ignored when the locales since the default resource would then be found in the first `for` iteration, before the fallback locale is tested.

Answer (score 1):

(This is an addition to my comment to have a more detailed explanation)

You could put the ressources in different folders, based on their language.

File tree could look like this:

- pathToRessources

  - DE

    - Images

      - Image1.png
      - Image2.png
    - Localization

      - MainPage // More for a website here....
      - Impressum
  - EN

    - ...

And using like a "file-localization-path-builder-class" (claiming best name ever)

```
public static Locale currentLocale = Locale.GERMAN;

public static String baseRessourcePath = "Path to your basic folder for ressources";

public static String getLocalizedPathToFile(String ressourcePath)
{
    return Paths.get(currentLocale.getLanguage(), ressourcePath).toString();
}
```

Wherever you need to load ressource just call your loader with

```
getLocalizedPath(PathToFile)
```

where **PathToFile** is like **/Images/Image1.png** or something else.

This should also be pretty easily be used for client applications.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I like your idea (upvoted), but in the meantime I [found the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27953622/400056) I was really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Having the resource to hold the name of the localized file is indeed a valid solution, but as you have mentioned is cumbersome. If you need to display HTML page in your application, why not to have small web server embedded, and have it server JSP pages? This way, the entire HTML will remain the same, and the pages themselves will be localized.

Another option, is to use a local templating engine (such as FreeMarker) and generate HTMLs dynamically before serving them.

Comment: Interesting idea, but not really suited for my needs, I'm afraid. I like to present help pages with long, formatted texts. Localized JSP pages seem to be even more work for this. Also, this feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Last but not least, it doesn't solve loading localized images.

Comment: This is exactly what Eclipse is doing - for the help they open a local instance of tomcat. Also, for localized images you will need to keep the image names as a localized resource. How many pages are we talking about?

Comment: Right now there's only one. I expect to need maybe a dozen or two. There's too much about this that makes me nervous. It seems that editing such a page is more cumbersome. Tomcat is larger than my app and I guess it has a higher memory footprint as well. It's a lot of work to set up and maintain, when all I want is display a HTML file in a WebView. I really appreciate the idea but there are way too many things about this that smell to me.

Comment: Tomcat is the eclispe way, smaller application usually use Jetty. Also, can you just open a web view to your own web server? If so, you can host those files on a server and pass the locale as parameter

Answer (score 0):

What about [`ListResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/list.html) ?

Define your bundles :

```
public class MyBundle_fr_FR extends ListResourceBundle
{
    public Object[][] getContents()
    {
        return new Object[][] 
        {
            { "welcome_file", getClass().getResource("Welcome_fr.html") },
            { "another_file", getClass().getResource("foo_fr.html") }
        };
    }
}

public class MyBundle_de_DE extends ListResourceBundle
{
    public Object[][] getContents()
    {
        return new Object[][] 
        {
            { "welcome_file", getClass().getResource("Welcome_de.html") },
            { "another_file", getClass().getResource("foo_de.html") }
        };
    }
}
```

And then use it like this :

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyBundle", Locale.GERMANY);
URL url = (URL) bundle.getObject("welcome_file");
```

Comment: That's just a variant of the filename-in-property-file scheme. That is, for each resource I need to add new entries in the ListResourceBundle. I would've put the filename in my `Localization.properties` file; your proposal has the advantage of returning an URL instead of "just" a filename, though.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are doing it is kind of weird for me. I developed some international applications and never used this approach. The maintenance cost of your approach is so high. Imagine that you would like to change one part of `welcome.html` file you need to change all other welcome files which is a huge effort.
the common solution for this problem in java is using [JSTL fmt taglib](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)  with getting help of some property files  containing key-value pair which the keys are fixed and the values change  according the the locale that you are in. For example you in your `Localization.properties` file you have key-value(s) like:

```
page.welcome.welcome=welcome
```

and you have another file with name `Localization_de.properties` that has the same key with different value

```
page.welcome.welcome=willkommen
```

Now in your `welcome.jsp` you may use something like this `<fmt:message key="page.welcome.welcome"/>` in order to render the proper value in your page. For images  you can get the same approach. just import the name of image into each property file as  key and name it properly as their value and use the key in your jsp. 
For i18n use eclipse plugins(like [Resource Bundel Editor](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-resourcebundle-editor)) to make the life easier for you.

In other languages framework that I used like django I've seen the same approach as above.

Comment: Do you really do this for long help files? If it's about localizing a file with, say, a dozen strings I'd say it's a annoying but you can do it. But what about a HTML page with 30 _paragraphs_, plus tables and lists? That seems very cumbersome and I wouldn't do it on other platforms like Mac, iOS or Android where you localize complete arbitrary files by placing them into the right directories. Especially when you localize, say, 30 help files: you'd end up with a _monster_ resource property file. Easy to leave dead entries in, too. That just feels so wrong to me.

Comment: Most of the applications that I worked on have been data centric and usually didn't have a lot of static files. We usually use and fetch localized data from database. For data shown to the user in view we usually put them on property files. For your specific problem I think apache has some facilities for static file internationalization but I haven't used it.